# A software for creating a 3D spatial density map from large data points

Tags: data-visualization, 3d, scientific-computing

I have a (time-dependent) system of ~100k moving points in a confined space. Each point has its own Cartesian coordinates and weight (w) in the form of ***(x,y,z;w)***.

I'm looking for a software/app/package to create a snapshot of the 3D spatial density map of these points. ([something like this](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/2013/130906/ncomms3414/fig_tab/ncomms3414_F3.html)). Like you see in this figure, the points are not going to be displayed individually, but only a transparent cloud will be drawn whose local intensity is proportional with the local number of points.

The final goal is to create a movie of the changing 3D spatial density with time.
So far, I have tried R, Matlab, Origin. But no success!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [python](http://python.org) + [Mayavi](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/) - the accepted answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286811/how-to-plot-a-3d-density-map-in-python-with-matplotlib) does almost exactly what you are looking for:

[image]